# Как запретить пролистывание страницы при зуме на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Занимаюсь версткой веб-сайта и столкнулся с проблемой при адаптации некоторых страниц. При нажатии на определенную кнопку у меня появляется окно на весь экран, которое не должно пролистываться. Для этого я ставлю `document.body.style.overflow='hidden'` в js и оно работает на десктопе, но на мобильных устройствах можно все равно пролистать страницу, уменьшая её и пролистывая двумя пальцами. Из-за этого внешний вид сайта страдает. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с таким и знает решение? Буду безумно благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Можно еще и уменьшение запретить тогда. Это решит проблему?

Comment: @Leonid подскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить уменьшение?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport  --> `user-scalable=no` или `minimum-scale=1.0`

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сафари даже так разрешает зумить

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант добавлять класс, который будет запрещать пролистывание страницы (`body.lock { overflow: hidden }`). Возможно понадобится сделать это отдельно в медиа запросе в css, но это уже код нужно смотреть.